# Parameterized path in "copy into" statement?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to parameterize the path used by a `copy into` statement in Snowflake's SQL? I'd like to do something like, for example: `copy into @temp_int_stage/test_$v from ...`, where $v is a SQL variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define variable in snowsql. For that you have to enable variable substitution. Later you can use variable with `&` operator

```
!define val = yourvalue
!set variable_substitution=True
copy into @temp_int_stage/test_&val from ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to accomplish this is through a Snowflake Stored Procedure.  You can't do it directly using a variable in the SQL Statement, though.

Comment: [sorry for the spam] Could this be accomplished with streams and tasks?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any programming interface to load files from stage to final target table you can do it. We are using python script to load our data from snowflake stage to target table. Where in copy command file path will be parameterized.

Else, you can use in snowflake stored procedure. I'm not sure, is there any way to execute directly.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to do it in Snowflake's SQL directly, but it seems it can't be done.